# repeat 2 elements in one v-for with vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

is there a way to repeat 2 elements with one `v-for` without extra element/container?

what I want to achieve is like this:

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td{
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td rowspan="2">itteration 1</td><td>value 1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>value 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td rowspan="2">itteration 2</td><td>value 1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>value 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td rowspan="2">itteration 3</td><td>value 1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>value 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td rowspan="2">and so on</td><td>value 1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>value 2</td></tr>
</table>
```

if I use code like below

```
<tr v-for="(i, k) in items" :key="k">
  <td rowspan="2">itteration {{ k + 1 }}</td>
  <td>value 1</td>
</tr>
<tr v-for="(i, k) in items" :key="k">
  <td>value 2</td>
</tr>
```

I got a result like this

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td{
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td roswpan="2">itteration 1</td><td>value 1</td></tr>
  <tr><td roswpan="2">itteration 2</td><td>value 1</td></tr>
  <tr><td roswpan="2">itteration 3</td><td>value 1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>value2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>value2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>value2</td></tr>
</table>
```

of-course I could use code like this

```
<tbody v-for="(i, k) in items" :key="k">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">itteration {{ k + 1 }}</td>
    <td>value 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>value 2</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

but I want to avoid that if possible.

any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Vue 3, it is now possible for a component to have multiple root nodes, so you can use something like this:

```js
const Example = {
  props: ["iteration"],
  template: `
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">iteration {{ iteration }}</td>
      <td>value 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>value 2</td>
    </tr>
  `
};

const App = {
  components: {
    Example
  },
  data() {
    return {
      items: ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
    }
  },
  template: `<Example v-for="(i, k) in items" v-bind:iteration="k" />`
};

Vue.createApp(App).mount("#app");
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.0-beta.14/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

In Vue 2 (tested on 2.5.13), you can use a `<template>` element with `v-for`, which can contain more than one child:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data() {
    return {
      items: ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="root">
  <table>
    <template v-for="(i, k) in items">
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">iteration {{ k + 1 }}</td>
        <td>value 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>value 2</td>
      </tr>
    </template>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: this tag creates its own scope? Cannot find docs for this tag hm?

Comment: @trainoasis the answer is quite old, and the docs have changed a lot since it was written. It looks like the typical style of writing Vue components has also changed in that time. The general consensus seems to be that you can use a `render` function to return an array, if you need to return more than one component.

Comment: (for vue 2) Would be fine if the linting wouldn't be conflicting... one is saying that template cannot have a key property... and then you put the key on the first element (first row in this case)but complaining again... also the k (index) variable seem not to work well